# How to preserve header rows using a Matrix

Tags: matrix, ssrs-2008

How to preserve header rows using a Matrix and I don't mean preserve them at the page level.

What currently happens.
When I click the plus/minus on the row the row data is replaced by the next groups data.

So ..
MyRow-45-60-04

After I click on this row I get this ..
MyRow-SecondRow-15-30-100

As you can see upon opening the main row the data is replaced by "SecondRow" on the same line.

I need this to drop down and show both rows plus all child row. This also needs to work for all rows beneath the parent row.

MyRow-45-60-04
  SecondRow-15-30-100
    ThidRow-85-74-5
      FourthRow-64-39-9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out a solution based on a Microsoft SSRS page.

Right click on the group cell of the row and create a row above, inside the group. This should move the cell and its contents up one row. Do this for each row group by clicking in the box of the row name. You should see a row/column step for each row group.

```
FirstGroup
           Second Group
                        ThirdGroup
```

As you can see they are separate on the screen but stepped.
Now grab the expression for SecondGroup and move it one cell backward. This will align it under FirstGroup. Do the same for ThirdGroup.

You now should have something like this

```
 FirstGroup
 SecondGroup
 ThirdGroup
```

Looks good but they are now on top of each other. Adjust the padding for each group. It looks pretty good by tens. The default is 2 so just add a 1 to the first one making it 12. Then increment the rest as you see fit.

The next issue is the column total is still stuck on the bottom row due to the fact you created rows above it. Fix this by copying that expression into the cells above it. Do not remove lower expression. You will need one for each row.

Last step is to delete the empty columns to the right of the moved cells. Make sure you do not delete the cells with expressions in them. In this example you would be deleting 2 empty columns

Your table should now look like this.

```
FirstGroup        |    <exp>  |  <totals>
  SecondGroup     |    <exp>  |  <totals>
    ThirdGroup    |    <exp>  |  <totals>
```

This example solves 2 issues at once. It keeps the group level information in tact when expanded and it also give the matrix a clean look.